# Dropdown menu select required if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm going to ask you a help with HTML/Javascript (I must not use Jquery).

I have a document with lots of checkboxes. Usually I check one or more checkboxes and I click the button Save to pass to another page. Only if I check the checkbox with the id "cool" it has to be mandatory to select one choice from the dropdown menu with id "list".
So if I select the checkbox "cool" and I don't select a choice from the dropmenu it must not be possible to save the page.
I tried several codes with javascript (script one and script two) but they don't work. Can you help me?

This is the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cool" name="Performance" value="ON">
```

This is the dropdown menu

```
<select id="list" name="Info">
         <option></option>
         <option>Cat</option>
         <option>Dog</option>
         <option>Bird</option>
        </select>
```

Script One I tried

```
<script>
   function scriptone()
     {
       var checkBox=document.getElementById("cool");
       if (checkBox.checked == true)
          {     document.getElementById("list").required =  true;
          } 
      }
</SCRIPT>
```

Script Two I tried

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("cool").addEventListener('change', function(){
        document.getElementById("list").required =  this.checked;
 }  
</SCRIPT>
```

Let me know if you need further information. Thank you.

Comment: I put an answer in several parts. Does it help you?

Comment: Yes, very good ideas. It helps

Answer (score 1):

You can put a listener to each element and disable the button if the conditions don't meet the requirements.

```js
const cool = document.getElementById("cool");
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

function checkDisabled() {
  submit.disabled = cool.checked && (list.value.length === 0);
}

cool.addEventListener('change', function(){
  checkDisabled()
})

list.addEventListener('change', function(){
  checkDisabled()
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cool" name="Performance" value="ON">

<select id="list" name="Info">
         <option></option>
         <option value="cat">Cat</option>
         <option value="dog">Dog</option>
         <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="submit">Next</button>
```

You can do even better, because it's not very UX friendly: only display the dropdown if the checkbox is checked using the `visibility` property.
Also, factorize the code:

```js
const cool = document.getElementById("cool");
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

function checkDisabled() {
  submit.disabled = cool.checked && (list.value.length === 0);
  list.style.visibility = cool.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}

[cool, list].forEach((x) => x.addEventListener('change', function(){
  checkDisabled()
}))

checkDisabled();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cool" name="Performance" value="ON">
<label for="cool">Cool</label>

<select id="list" name="Info">
         <option></option>
         <option value="cat">Cat</option>
         <option value="dog">Dog</option>
         <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="submit">Next</button>
```

Writing `document.getElementById` everytime can be annoying, if you're not using any library, I suggest you use a shorthand:

```js
const $ = (x) => document.getElementById(x)

function checkDisabled() {
  $("submit").disabled = $("cool").checked && ($("list").value.length === 0);
  $("list").style.visibility = $("cool").checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}

[$("cool"), $("list")].forEach((x) => x.addEventListener('change', function(){
  checkDisabled()
}))

checkDisabled();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cool" name="Performance" value="ON">
<label for="cool">Cool</label>

<select id="list" name="Info">
         <option></option>
         <option value="cat">Cat</option>
         <option value="dog">Dog</option>
         <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="submit">Next</button>
```

I also suggest you put a warning, like this:

```js
const $ = (x) => document.getElementById(x)

function checkDisabled() {
  $('submit').disabled = $('cool').checked && ($('list').value.length === 0);
  $('list').style.visibility = $('cool').checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  $('error').style.display = ($('cool').checked && $('list').value.length === 0) ? 'inline' : 'none';
}

[$("cool"), $("list")].forEach((x) => x.addEventListener('change', function(){
  checkDisabled()
}))

checkDisabled();
```

```css
#error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cool" name="Performance" value="ON">
<label for="cool">Cool</label>

<select id="list" name="Info">
         <option value="">-- choose an animal--</option>
         <option value="cat">Cat</option>
         <option value="dog">Dog</option>
         <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="submit">Next</button>
<span id="error">Choose an animal</span>
```

Comment: don't forget to validate my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the `onClick` on your `<input />` element, that is why your function is never running.

Try this out:

```js
function scriptone() {
  const checkBox = document.getElementById("cool");
  const listElem = document.getElementById("list");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    list.disabled = false;
  } else {
    list.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cool" name="Performance" value="ON" onclick="scriptone()">
<select id="list" name="Info">
  <option></option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Bird</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "Script Two" does work, See your code in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkcf5d19/1/).

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cool">Force Required</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cool" name="Performance" value="ON">
  <br />
  <label for="list">Select Choice</label>
  <select id="list" name="Info">
         <option></option>
         <option>Cat</option>
         <option>Dog</option>
         <option>Bird</option>
        </select>
  <br /> 
  <input type="submit">
</form>

(function() {
   document.getElementById("cool").addEventListener('change', function(){
        document.getElementById("list").required =  this.checked;
   });
})();
```